# How to set the value of mountPath using env variable in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

i want to mount host path /a/b/c/pod_name to container path /a/b/c/pod_name, how can i do that?

```
      env:
      - name: MY_POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
     volumeMounts:
     - mountPath: /a/b/b/d/${MY_POD_NAME}
        name: test
        subPathExpr: $(MY_POD_NAME)
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /a/b/c/d
        type: "DirectoryOrCreate"
      name: test
```

and what mounted to container path is just literal '${MY_POD_NAME}', i want it to be the real name of pod.

Comment: K8s ignores dynamic values/variables present in manifests. Consider using tools like kustomize or helm for this kind of thing.

Comment: If this was successful, it seems like it would create an unpredictably-named directory on an unpredictable node.  What is your actual goal with this setup?

Comment: @David Maze I want the host path to be consistent with the path mounted inside the container.

Comment: Why does that matter?  The directory you're trying to create here isn't really "persistent" at all – if your Pod gets deleted and recreated, it will have a different name and won't necessarily be on the same host – do you need some other persistence mechanism, or an `emptyDir:` volume?